# How to correctly move a mail folder from one mailbox to another?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to move folders from a user mailbox to a shared mailbox using

```
 graphClient.Users[completedMailbox].MailFolders[folderID].Move(fPrincipalId).Request().PostAsync();
```

note: the above was working for many years until recently.

So I am wondering if something has changed as other people are experiencing the same, see my other post about the issue here but no resolution.

[Microsoft QnA - Mailbox move in progress. Try again later., The user and the mailbox are in different Active Directory sites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/403433/mailbox-move-in-progress-try-again-later-the-user.html?childToView=408444#answer-408444)

In the link above you can see I have tied directly on the Graph API Explorer

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/office@w*g.com/mailFolders/AAiSjAAA=/move
{
"destinationId": "AA*WyUAAA="
}
```

which returns

```
{
"error": {
"code": "ErrorMailboxMoveInProgress",
"message": "Mailbox move in progress. Try again later., The user and the mailbox are in different Active Directory sites.",
"innerError": {
"date": "2021-05-20T16:14:04",
"request-id": "c5f45ede-c5ad-40da-8528-bbafa91dede5",
"client-request-id": "***"
}
}
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I thought I would be clever and instead of moving the folder I would create the folder in the shared mailbox and move each of the messages,but no, same error.  Also tried to copy a message from the mailbox to the shared mailbox, same error.  I can fetch messages, create new folders okay but cannot move or copy.  All works fine in Outlook client.

Comment: Also tried a different shared mailbox to copy a message to, same error.

Comment: (1) Open a support ticket from the microsoft portal and verify is there any activity happening related to mailbox or not. (2) Check with your admin/support and validate whether the user and the mailbox are in different Active Directory sites or in the same AAD.

Comment: Did you finally succeed in moving a mail from user-mailbox to a shared-mailbox?